# Apple II SCSI: Maximum drive / partition size?

Tags: apple-ii, scsi

Using an "SCA to 50-pin adapter", it is possible to use a 300 gig Ultra-320 SCSI drive from 2004, with an Apple II outfitted with the Apple SCSI controller.

It seems possible for the electronics to be capable of accessing more storage than what the available software is currently designed to support. So...

Looking at the electronics only, what is the theoretical maximum block number / disk capacity accessible by the old SCSI controller?

If the old controller has technical limits on the maximum accessible block number, is there a way for the drive to overcome those limits?

Software-wise, what is the maximum usable logical volume or number of volumes that can be created?

Comment: I think SCSI is completely backwards compatible, so in theory you should be able to connect the earliest SCSI drive to the latest SCSI controller and vice-versa.

Comment: @bjb this is almost correct, you should ask your own question for that if it hasn't been answered.

Comment: @Dale Mahalko do you have any documentation on the scsi interface? I was only aware of the mfm drive. I think the largest drive I saw advertised was 40mb, but that was from before prodos.

Comment: @bjb: Except maybe for [SASI drives](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/how-to-connect-an-apple-iie-to-an-external-sider-hard-disk-drive). Also, there were SCSI versions.

Comment: Also, if you're including the IIgs, the maximum partition size is [2GB with HFS](http://www.bigmessowires.com/2015/07/02/2-gb-smartport-hard-drive-for-apple-iigs/).

Comment: @Nick Westgate I do not believe the original poster was including the IIgs which is a 16-bit machine not the 8-Bit of the prior generation. Also SASI drives are a fully functional subset of SCSI-1 which is also 8-bit.

Comment: dale, if Brian's answer doesn't answer your question could you tell us what you feel is missing or otherwise mark it as the answer so others may gain incite from your success?

Comment: It looks like the Apple II may be capable of Mac HFS under GS/OS, but I have not had time to try it. This would allow the entire 300GB to be usable, but HFS has 65535 file limit, and apparently only accessible via GS/OS, not ProDOS 8, and what would you even do with this amount of space on a system with a max of 1 megabyte/sec SCSI access rate? 85 hrs to read/write entire 300gig drive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SCSI controller is not a limiting factor. The Apple II SCSI controller electronics, and SCSI protocol, would support accessing the blocks of a *very large disk*. However, managing those blocks is all done by some DOS software, and ProDOS imposes some more severe constraints.

ProDOS manages the disk as volumes and partitions, and does both these in a manner appropriate for an 8-bit, 64 KB computer - *sparingly*. Volumes are associated with slots, and partitions are kept small (by modern standards) to minimize the file system management overhead.

For ProDOS 2.0 and above, the maximum partition size is 32 MB and the maximum number of partitions is, theoretically, 13. To get to 13 you have to minimize other cards in the system and remove Floppy Drive Controllers. 32M x 13 would be a maximum of 416 MB for ProDOS HD volumes.

Comment: Of course, back in those days, 416 MB was a *massive* amount of storage. I think people don't quite appreciate how much a megabyte really was back then...

Comment: Especially given lack of any real networking... I had a want to say 300 MB hard drive on my Apple IIGS (partitioned basically as you said ... ten folders sounds right) and basically every month would add 1-2 800k floppies (softdisk) and there was basically no way I was going to ever fill it .... then I went off to college with a 540 MB hard drive on a 486 with 10 Mbps ethernet and I think I filled that up about a month in or less